# Defining Object Literals with Flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I am attempting to define this object:

```
let apiFormatted: {"barcode": number, "id": number}  = {"barcode": this_barcode.barcode, "id": this.props.currentJob}
```

The error I am getting from Flow is:

```
Flow: object literal. This type is incompatible with object type
```

I have attempted {[string]: number, [string]: number} as well with no success. I am new to Flow and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Doing `let obj = {"barcode": this_barcode.barcode, "id": this.props}` is totally fine

Comment: Why is there no way to define this type and/or why is it unnecessary? For now I pass `apiFormatted` into an argument and Flow requests a type. I have done this : `apiFormatted: {}` and it works.

Comment: `let apiFormatted: {"barcode": number, "id": number}  = {"barcode": 1, "id": 1}` is perfectly valid. Check types of `this_barcode.barcode` and `this.props.currentJob`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, some words about flow:

flowtype is a typechecker. That means it checks if you use the variables the way you have declared them. This has two advantages:

1) you can find errors while you write your code, and it does not occur when you execute it, which makes your code more bulletproof

2) it makes the code more readable, therefore its easier for others to understand the code and you can work in a team.

The only disadvantage is that you need to type much more. However flow *infers* much of the types, that means that it checks for the types even if you don't tell it to. Therefore

```
let obj = {barcode : this_barcode.barcode, id : this.props};
```

actually infers the type:

```
{barcode: number, id: number}
```

That means that the following won't work:

```
obj.barcode = "fails"
```

as flow infers a number, but I tried to assign a string.
When you want to pass it to a function and do:

```
function open(barcode : {}){
  console.log(barcode.id);
}
```

This is dangerous, beause you can do

```
open({});
```

And it won't tell you that the code wont work as wanted. So there it makes sense to define *id* as aproperty:

```
function open(barcode : { id : number }){
```

If your object has many propertes that are extensively used, it's probably a good idea to define an [Interface](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/interfaces/) once:

```
interface Barcode {
  barcode : number;
  id : number
}

let obj : Barcode = {barcode:1, id:2};
```